# An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for system.data: invariant-name is constrained to be unique

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

### i'm getting error in my SQL SERVER when click in object explorer to open table, design, select top 200 rows, etc... i'm getting this of error.

Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. (SQLEditors)

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for system.data: Column 'InvariantName' is constrained to be unique.  Value 'FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient' is already present. (C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config line 154) (System.Configuration)

---

### and also i'm getting same error in my Visual studio 2015 when i add existing Project and built it getting same error , and i'm unable add new ADO.NET connect in my Visual Studio 2015 when i click NEW Connection and when enter database server name it automatically closing new connection window. so please get out of this...

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Error 175: The ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient' is either not registered in the machine or application config file, or could not be loaded. See the inner exception for details.    Biznaltic   C:\Users\mukesh\Source\Repos\Biznaltic\Biznaltic\Models\Model.edmx  7